what is the Sthala Purana of the "bleeding idol" temple in Telangana?
https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/life-style/soul-search/this-lord-narsimha-idol-in-india-bleeds-from-the-navel-heres-why/photostory/106213965.cms

The heart of the temple is the idol of Lord Narasimha which is no less than a marvel and a wonder. What sets this idol apart from others is the soft texture of Lord Narasimha's idol. So much so that it is said that if you press the idol, an indent forms in his skin, and if you poke too hard blood starts to ooze out of him. As the idol bleeds from time to time, the pujari and priests over there constantly cover Lord Narasimha’s idol with sandalwood paste to stop the bleeding.

Is there a scientific explanation of this phenomenon?
